# Is a "2D fft" the same as two 1D fft's?

Tags: c++, cuda, fft

I have a cuda code that I have implemented several C2C 2D FFT's in. They all use the same plan, but for some reason, the times on the 2D FFT's are large, and seem to vary quite a bit. Same data size FFT's seem to take anywhere from 0.4s to 1.8s

This is for a 1920x1080 FFT. Do those times seem reasonable?

Anyhow - I have had good experience with CUDA 1-D batched FFTs being fast. is it the same to take a 1D FFT across the rows, and then again across the columns of a matrix to give the same results as this 2D FFT? I have experience FFTs happening in a few hundreths of a second across larger data sets for 1D FFTs before, so I was hoping to maybe fix some of these results.

Thanks

Comment: Remember that there's also an implied transform going on here, whose access pattern may slow things down considerably.

Comment: Those times are very high - FFTW on a 2.67 GHz Core i7 will do these in < 100 ms.

Answer (score 6):

A 2D transform of a 1K by 1K image requires 2K 1D transforms. Therefore those times seem reasonable.

For more information have a look at: http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/dft/